# Proof of the Baire Category Theorem

Tags: general-topology

I stumbled upon an exercises that asked me to prove Baire's problem by myself.

Here's my try, where $X$ is the considered set and $D_i$ their subsets:
We just need to prove that given $D_1$ and $D_2$ dense, we have that their intersection is also dense.
Now let $x$ be an element of $X$ outside the closure of $D_1 \cap D_2$, so that there exists a subset $U$ of $X$ containing $x$ so that $U \cap (D_1 \cap D_2)$ is the empty set; but we have that for density of both $D_i$'s, $U \cap D_1 \neq \varnothing$, so that $(U \cap D_1) \cap D_2$ cannot be the empty set.

I've found no flaws in my proof, but I think it's too plain and simple to be completely corrected

Comment: Yes. It's not too hard to show the **finite** intersection of open dense sets is dense. But the Baire theorem makes the much stronger claim that, when the topology of the space is sufficiently nice, the **countably infinite** intersection of open dense sets is dense. It is not possible to induct from the finite case to the infinite case here, so, your proof is incomplete

Comment: Also even for the finite case your dense sets need to be open as well, you didn’t seem to use that and instead simply asserted that $U\cap D_1\neq \emptyset$ implies $(U\cap D_1)\cap D_2\neq\emptyset$, which does not follow at all in general ($D_1$ and $D_2$ can be disjoint in general!)

Comment: Sorry but doesn't induction work for the countable case as it is linked with integers?

Comment: @temp induction extends the result from $2$-fold intersections to arbitrary finite intersections, Not to countable intersections

Comment: @temp No. Every finite intersection of open sets is open, but it's not always true that infinite intersections are open. E.g. of finite induction not working for infinite case

Comment: As for actually proving Baire's theorem... there are many questions about that on this site